# Stuck on TicTacToe checking if the move is valid C++

Tags: c++, tic-tac-toe

Hi I am a beginner and I am making a console tic tac toe c++ before I try to get it done in unity3d but that's another story, I got stuck on the get_move1() function, as far as how can I check if the array has a 1 or a -1 if it does then is full and the function should say in an invalid move, can this be done any other way besides 2d array, my program just hangs with no error, I haven't work on the other functions yet so they are just empty for now. Thanks for your help.

```
*init_board and board_state array
get_move function to determine if the move is legal if it is then
fill board_state array and show X or O on the board with another array
check_win
*/

/* layout of board
cout <<  "   1 | 2 | 3  \n"
         "     |   |    \n"
       "  - - - - - -   \n"
         "   4 | 5 | 6  \n"
         "     |   |    \n"
       "  - - - - - -   \n"
         "   7 | 8 | 9  \n"
         "     |   |    \n" << endl;

 cout << "   " <<board_array[0] <<" | " <<  board_array[1] << " | " << board_array[2] <<    "\n"
         "     |   |    \n"
       "  - - - - - -   \n"
         "   " <<board_array[3] <<" | " <<  board_array[4] << " | " << board_array[5] <<    "\n"
         "     |   |    \n"
       "  - - - - - -   \n"
         "   " <<board_array[6] <<" | " <<  board_array[7] << " | " << board_array[8] <<    "\n"
         "     |   |    \n" << endl;

         */

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//declare global variables

int board_state[3][3] = { {0,0,0},  //here the 2d array is initialized and set to 0 for empty
                          {0,1,0},
                          {0,0,0} };

char gui_state[3][3];               //2d array to represent the X and O on the board




//declare functions

void init_board();
void get_move1();



int main()
{
    init_board();
        get_move1();
}

void init_board()
{
    cout << "   1 | 2 | 3 \n"
            "     |   |   \n"
            "  - - - - - -  \n"
            "   4 | 5 | 6 \n"
            "     |   |   \n"
            "  - - - - - -  \n"
            "   7 | 8 | 9 \n"
            "     |   |   \n"
            " **Tic Tac Toe ** " << endl;
}

void get_move1() // In this function player's moves are taken and make sure they are valid if so update arrays
{
    int player1_move;
    int i;
    int j;
    bool invalid_move;


    cout << "Player 1 enter move" << endl;
    cin >> player1_move;

    //need to check if the players's move is valid

    for (i=0; i < 3; i++)          //if array is 1 or -1 then move is invalid
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 3; i++)
            if (board_state[i][j] == 1 || board_state[i][j] == -1)
            {
                invalid_move = true;
            }


    } cout << "You entered an invalid move" << endl;

}

void get_move2()
{

}

void game_state()
{

}

void check_win()
{

}
```

so I decided to go for a one dimensional array to keep it simple for now

```
int board_state[9] = {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};  //here the 1d array is initialized and set to 0 for empty

void get_move1() // In this function player's moves are taken and make sure they are valid if so update arrays
{
    int player1_move;
    int array_index;
    int player1_fill = 1;


    cout << "Player 1 enter move" << endl;
    cin >> player1_move;

    //need to check if the players's move is valid

    array_index = player1_move -1;

    if (board_state[array_index] == 1 || board_state[array_index] == -1)
    {
        cout << "Invalid move" << endl;
    }

    else board_state[array_index] = player1_fill;
```

Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
for(j = 0; j < 3; i++)
```

should be:

```
for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
```

Answer (score 0):

invalid_move is not intialized properly

Also if the cells are labelled 1.9.. you need to map it (i,j) correctly and update the array.
You are not updating the array with **player1_move**. For this you don't need the for loop at all

Comment: so I have changed invalid_move = false; and yeah I haven't got that far once the move is valid then my next step was to update the array

Comment: `invalid_move` is indeed initialized properly.

In C++, all lvalues are default-initialized, and the default ctor, so to speak, for scalars, is the zero assignment, so it's declared false.

Read section 8.5 of the C++ standard.

Answer (score 0):

After the `for` loop add this code:

```
if (invalid_move)
{
    cout << "Invalid move.\n";
}
```

Comment: yes I just add that in, well I think 2d arrays is just way out of my league I will represent everything in 1d array

Answer (score 0):

The problem is after discover an improper move, the loop does not stop so the invalid_move is overwritten.

```
invalid_move=false;//and here
for (i=0; i < 3&&invalid_move==false; i++)   //Watch out here
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 3&&invalid_move==false; j++)
            if (board_state[i][j] == 1 || board_state[i][j] == -1)
            {
                invalid_move = true;
            }


    } cout << "You entered an invalid move" << endl;
```